# How to set different colors for all icons in BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, material-design, bottomnavigationview

I am making an Android app with a bottom navigation bar. I know how to set the same color to all icons, but i want to do the the thing as in the [image]
(I want every icon to have a different color), even though that Material Design guidelines say not to.

It is a Java application, everything is working good. I just need to set different colors to every icon in the bar.

Menu .xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/id1"
        android:icon="pathtoicon1"
        android:title="Text1" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/id2"
        android:icon="@pathtoicon2"
        android:title="Text2" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/id3"
        android:icon="@pathtoicon3"
        android:title="Text3" />

</menu>
```

In the activity .xml file I have this code related to the bar:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"/>
```

EDIT: I tried changing the colors of vector assets of icons, but had no success.

EDIT II: I have these lines related to the BNV in my MainActivity.java

> BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView =
>   findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
>           bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

I tried adding the

> setHasOptionsMenu(true);

to my FragmentName.java and overriding the public void `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)` in the same class with the code given by @Vincent and appending

```
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
```

to it, but the function is never invoked. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

**In onCreateOptionsMenu**

```
  MenuItem menuItem1 = menu.findItem(R.id.id1);
  Drawable newIcon1 =  menuItem1.getIcon();
  newIcon1.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.yourcolorincolorsxml), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
  menuItem1.setIcon(newIcon1);

  MenuItem menuItem2 = menu.findItem(R.id.id1);
  Drawable newIcon2 =  menuItem2.getIcon();
  newIcon2.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.yourcolorincolorsxml), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
  menuItem2.setIcon(newIcon2);

  MenuItem menuItem3 = menu.findItem(R.id.id1);
  Drawable newIcon3 =  menuItem3.getIcon();
  newIcon3.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.yourcolorincolorsxml), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
  menuItem3.setIcon(newIcon3);
```

Comment: I just can not manage to get onCreateOptionsMenu invoked (Logs show it is not invoked). I googled a lot and not found any working solution. Edited the question with more code.

Comment: @JustSpam Do you only have fragments or also a MainActivity class? For example where you manage a viewpager for the fragments to be displayed?

Comment: @JustSpam If so, override onCreateOptionsMenu in your MainActivity and not in your fragment

Comment: @Vince in any case you can't change the text color in this way

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Thought the question was too change the color of the icon, which does work for me this way.

Comment: @Vince Check also the image in question.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Couldn't see the image before so yeah this is only for icons i guess.